# How to use interceptors with services in nestjs

Tags: service, nestjs, interceptor

How can i use interceptors with services?

I tried use it like with controllers but it didnt work.

```
import { 
    Injectable,
    UseInterceptors, 
} from '@nestjs/common';

import MyInterceptor from '...'

@Injectable()
export class Service {
    @UseInterceptors(MyInterceptor)
    public anyFunc() {
       // logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't. That's not a feature.

Interceptors were designed to enhance controllers (+ [graphql stuff](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/other-features)), not providers. That's why the [*binding interceptors*](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors#binding-interceptors) section in the docs only mention controllers.